# Issues Installing TensorFlow: Trust Store Feature Error

Tags: python, pip, truststore

**Context**:
I am attempting to install TensorFlow on my system.
**Issue Encountered:**
When trying to install TensorFlow, I encounter the following error message: "Error: To use the trust store feature, 'truststore' must be installed into pip's current environment."
**Subsequent Problem:
**Attempting to install 'truststore' results in the same error message. It seems to be a "chicken and egg" situation, where neither TensorFlow nor truststore can be installed first due to the dependency on each other.
**Question:
**How can I resolve this installation issue? Is there a workaround or a specific sequence of steps that I should follow to successfully install TensorFlow and the required 'truststore'?

I have tried looking on stack overflow but I have not found any similar issues. I have python 3.10.11.

Comment: perhaps read https://pypi.org/project/truststore/ and see if it helps